# python regex split string to each char but keep anything in brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to split a string looks like this:

```
a = 'sdfLKC[m2G]TO'
```

the output looks like this:

```
b = ['s', 'd', 'f', 'L', 'K', 'C', '[m2G]', 'T', 'O']
```

My knowledge of regex is basic, and my code is

```
b = re.split(r'(\[.+?\])', a)
```

but the output is `['sdfLKC', '[m2G]', 'TO']`, I also want split each character if they are not in the brackets, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to find any single word character or a string between 2 square bracket.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w|\[[^\]]+\]',a)
['s', 'd', 'f', 'L', 'K', 'C', '[m2G]', 'T', 'O']
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `re.findall` ? ie, do matching instead of splitting.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[[^\[\]]*\]|.', a)
['s', 'd', 'f', 'L', 'K', 'C', '[m2G]', 'T', 'O']
```